# Which function in Scala does convert java.lang.Integer (null) to scala Int (zero)?

Tags: scala

Discovered an unexpected behaviour recently (thanks to unit-tests).

Scala: 2.13.[4,6]

Code example:

```
scala> def pri(value: Int): Int = value
def pri(value: Int): Int

scala>val jInt: java.lang.Integer = null
val jInt: Integer = null

scala> pri(jInt)
val res0: Int = 0
```

I'd expect a `NullPointerException` here, but obviously Java `Integer` `null` is implictly converted to `Int` zero.

Scala's `Predef.scala.Integer2int` doesn't seem to be called:

```scala
implicit def Integer2int(x: java.lang.Integer): Int         = x.intValue
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Scala, the `Int` type corresponds to java `int`.

The Scala type system is devided into `AnyVal` and `AnyRef` hierarchies, both of which are subtypes of `Any`.

This `AnyVal` hierarchy has `Int`, `Long` etc. corresponding to Java primitive types. And these `AnyVal`s can be `boxed` to convert to corresponding `AnyRef` type (which is `Integer` for `Int`).

---

Type casting from `Int` to `Integer` (called `boxing`) happens by `Int.box` call, and this implementation comes from runtime implementation `scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.boxToInteger` which is defined as,

```java
public static java.lang.Integer boxToInteger(int i) {
    return java.lang.Integer.valueOf(i);
}
```

So, this first adapts the `i: Int` to a `int i` which is then converted to `Integer` using `java.lang.Integer.valueOf(i)`.

Similarly, the type casting from `Integer` to `Int` (called `unboxing`) is done by `Int.unbox`. Amd this implementation comes from runtime implementation `scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToInt` which is defined as,

```java
public static int unboxToInt(Object i) {
    return i == null ? 0 : ((java.lang.Integer)i).intValue();
}
```

Notice that `null` check in `null ? 0 : ((java.lang.Integer)i).intValue()`. This `unboxing` has this little "improvement" to "increase null safety" but can `throw` a `ClassCastException` as the input can be any `Object`.

---

Scala Predef has following two `implicits` to `implicitly` do this type casting whenever required.

```scala
implicit def int2Integer(x: Int): java.lang.Integer = x.asInstanceOf[java.lang.Integer]

implicit def Integer2int(x: java.lang.Integer): Int = x.asInstanceOf[Int]
```

Notice that starting with `Scala 2.12.0` these methods to a type casting and do not call any methods like `x.intValue` (this was done till `Scala 2.11.x`, where you will see the same `NullPointerException` as you see in Java, but then it was inconsistent with explicit `Int.box` calls, which might have been the reason for the change of `implicit definitions`).

---

Scala-Java interop has a lot more "unexpected" cases, so you need to be very carefull when you use Scala with almost any Java library (and interestingly we use Java libraries for almost everything).

Here are some surprizes just with `int`, `Int` and `Integer`.

```java
public class JavaIntMagic {

    public static int toPrimitiveInt(Integer integer) {
        return integer;
    }

    public static Integer toInteger(int i) {
        return i;
    }

}
```

```scala
object ScalaIntMagic {
  def toPrimitiveInt(integer: java.lang.Integer): Int = integer

  def toInteger(i: Int): java.lang.Integer = i
}
```

These implementations have different behaviours when called from Scala and Java code.

```java
public class JavaMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer integer = null;

        int i1 = ScalaIntMagic.toPrimitiveInt(integer);
        // 0

        int i2 = JavaIntMagic.toPrimitiveInt(integer);
        // fails with NullPointerException

        Integer integer1 = ScalaIntMagic.toInteger(integer);
        // fails with NullPointerException

        Integer integer2 = JavaIntMagic.toInteger(integer);
        // fails with NullPointerException
    }

}
```

```scala
object ScalaMain {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val integer: java.lang.Integer = null

    val i1: Int = ScalaIntMagic.toPrimitiveInt(integer)
    // 0

    val i2: Int = JavaIntMagic.toPrimitiveInt(integer)
    // fails with NullPointerException

    val integer1: java.lang.Integer = ScalaIntMagic.toInteger(integer)
    // 0
    // why ? because the "null safe" unboxing strikes again

    val integer2: java.lang.Integer = JavaIntMagic.toInteger(integer)
    // 0
    // why ? because the "null safe" unboxing strikes again

  }

}
```

When using `JDBC` or other java drivers, don't be surprised when your database tables magically have some numbers as `0` instead of the expected `null` (or write failures). Add more and more unit tests (even for something which might look very trivial).

It's weird that, on the one hand, we don't have any "pure" Scala libraries for fundamental stuff like networking, databases, etc. and rely heavily on Java libraries wrapped in Scala API's, yet on the other hand, we don't put any emphasis on consistent and predictable Java interop (even for very fundamental stuff like int, boolean, bytes) for reliable usage of those libraries in Scala ecosystem.

Comment: The missing piece for me is where is it defined that "the type casting from Integer to Int (called unboxing) is done by Int.unbox. " I guess it is hardcoded somewhere.

Comment: that will be part of Scala compiler. I think here - https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.6/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/ast/TreeInfo.scala#L43